# nagios sending notifications to wrong contacts

Tags: nagios

I'm having a small issue that has been bugging me for some time now, and now it's time to fix it :)

I have a Nagios Core 3.5 install running. In the Nagios configuration, we have a couple of service templates defined, all of these have a contact defined. We have some services that have to notify a different contact than the default contact defined at the service.

According to what I have read [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectinheritance.html) I would expect the service definition to overwrite the default contact.

Example config:

```
define service{
        name                            generic-service-5min
        notifications_enabled           1
        contacts                        contact1
        notification_options            w,u,c,r
        notification_interval           60
        notification_period             businessday
        register                        0
        }

define service{
        use                     generic-service-5min
        host_name               HOST1
        service_description     CustomService
        check_command           CustomService
        contacts                Contact2
}
```

Maybe my understanding of this is incorrect and is this how it should work. But hopefully we can find a way that doesn't lead to messages to two different contacts but only one.

Thanks for any information and/or insights.

Comment: If you want to send notification just the Contact2, it's correct. If you want to send to the original and Contact2 use +Contact2... Info: https://serverfault.com/questions/520888/possible-to-override-contacts-for-just-one-nagios-host-group

Comment: Well I'm getting a notification on both contacts so I'm doing something wrong, but i'n not sure what.